# python selenium Chain for loop (loop inside a loop ) to iterate element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, datepicker

Below is my code. I'm trying to download zip file(s) by iterating through a drop box, then manually entering the from and to dates. The issue is, i am unable to input my 2nd value for from_date i.e i am unable to get out of the inner for loop.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
date_from=['02-01-2000','02-01-2001','02-01-2002','02-01-2003','02-01-2004','02-01-2005','02-01-2006','02-01-2007','02-01-2008','02-01-2009','02-01-2010','02-01-2011','02-01-2012','02-01-2013','02-01-2014','02-01-2015','02-01-2016','02-01-2017'
]
date_to=['31-12-2000','31-12-2001','31-12-2002','31-12-2003','31-12-2004','31-12-2005','31-12-2006','31-12-2007','31-12-2008','31-12-2009','31-12-2010','31-12-2011','31-12-2012','31-12-2013','31-12-2014','31-12-2015','31-12-2016','31-12-2017']
browser.get('https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_pepb.htm')

lists=['NIFTY 50',
'NIFTY Next 50',
'NIFTY Auto',
'NIFTY Bank',
'NIFTY Energy',
'NIFTY Financial Services',
'NIFTY FMCG',
'NIFTY IT',
'NIFTY Media',
'NIFTY Metal',
'NIFTY Pharma',
'NIFTY Private Bank',
'NIFTY PSU Bank',
'NIFTY Realty']
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="IndexName"]'))
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#yield4').click()
for list in lists:
    select.select_by_visible_text(list)
    for date1 in date_from:
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromDate').send_keys(date1)
        for date2 in date_to:
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#toDate').send_keys(date2)
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#get').click()
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(150, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('html body div#container div.content_big div#wrapper_btm div.main_content div.content div.archives div#replacetext.tabular-data-historic table tbody tr.alt td a.historical-csv-downld').click()
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromDate').clear()
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#toDate').clear() #after clearing the cell value, im not able to input the second value from the list


browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue lies in the second to last line of the inner loop where you are clearing the #fromDate. The inner loop only sets the #toDate and so if you clear the #fromDate, it won’t get set until the inner loop finishes. Rather, you should only clear the #toDate in the inner loop and then, after the inner loop finishes, in the outter loop, clear the #fromDate. For example:

```
for date1 in fromDates:
    # set fromDate
    for date2 in toDates:
        # set toDate
        # do thing
        # clear toDate
    # clear fromDate
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment you want to make the first fromDate with the first toDate etc. to do this, you can loop through indicies rather than the elements in each list:

```
assert(len(dates_from) == len(dates_to))
for i in range(len(dates_from)):
    date1 = dates_from[i]
    date2 = dates_to[i]
    # use dates
```

This structure in your code would look like:

```
for list in lists:
    select.select_by_visible_text(list)
    for i in range(len(date_from)):
        date1 = date_from[i]
        date2 = date_to[i]
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromDate').send_keys(date1)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#toDate').send_keys(date2)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#get').click()
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(150, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('html body div#container div.content_big div#wrapper_btm div.main_content div.content div.archives div#replacetext.tabular-data-historic table tbody tr.alt td a.historical-csv-downld').click()
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#fromDate').clear()
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#toDate').clear()
```

Comment: yes, that is right. but if i do so, then only after the inside for loop finishes the outside loop acts. That's not how i intend to do. I want one from_date matched with one to_date and so on.! any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the bottom of my answer to reflect how to do that :)

Comment: Thanks for the code Rohan, but honestly I'm unaware what it does? or to put other way, im unsure of where to insert this code.! Sorry for the trouble , but a little more help.! :-)

Comment: I added a block at the bottom to show you how I would change your looping structure to incorporate the technique I'm recommending. Good luck!